# Command line VOB to AVI/MP4 with good quality and deinterlace

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd, video-encoding, mencoder, avi

I have some VOB files, grabbed from DVDs. I need to make AVI/MP4 files for uploading online. The original resolution is 720p and I want 720p, but need to scale as the pixels are not square (720x480 to

I want to do it with the command line; whether it's mencoder or ffmpeg (or even vlc if I can master its command line) is immaterial. But despite all googling I'm getting dodgy quality, notably, bad deinterlacing. Moreover some mencoder options I find are no longer valid anyway.

(I want MPEG4/lavc encoding; let's not bother with x264).

I would appreciate examples that give good quality deinterlaced MP4/AVI from VOB files. Which tool is used is immaterial as long as it's commonly available under Linux.

EDIT: here is the output of `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i file.VOB` 
 . The subtitle track, however, is not needed.

```
Input #0, mpeg, from 'deathscene_from14_40.VOB':
  Duration: 00:35:51.24, start: 1068.184978, bitrate: 7986 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xa0]: Audio: pcm_dvd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:3[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
```

Comment: @K7AAY I have added the material requested. I've seen some references, but there are too many options and I just can't work out the right ones, notably the deinterlacer settings that would work as well as what VLC uses for display.I'll try the examples from the ArchLinux wiki, thanks for the link! Two-pass x264 and separate audio sound like overkill but might work (if the upload in x264 works after that).

Comment: Excellent! You ran `cat *.VOB > output.vob && ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i output.vob`to concatenate the VOB files, then find what stream has MPEG-2 video, which have audio, and which kind of audio.  The Data stream, #0:2, is also superfluous, as you won't need a DVD menu. http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Audio-Decoders and http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MEncoder are useful references.